# Understanding JQuery variable scope

Tags: jquery, function, variables

I am having an issue understanding variable scope. I have illustrated an example below explaining my issue. Assume I have a bunch of div's with the class .btn and each of them have a unique ID stored in data-id.

When a div is clicked, I would like to call myFunction with a string passed into it, so it can be used in the function. The issue I run into is that when I define a variable in the function that I want to be conditional based on $(this) of the click function, the called function says it's not define

I understand that it isn't defined in the called function, but I am not sure how to solve this solution

See codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rlFyu

```
function myFunction(data) {
  var a = $(this).attr('data-id');
  console.log(a);
  return data;
}


$('.btn').click(function(){
  myFunction('variable');
});
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is `undefined`?

Comment: The variable a. If I define it in the click function, then it isn't undefined.

Comment: variable `a` is window..

Comment: I would like console.log(a) in the function to output the data-id value of whatever div was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is `window` in the scope of `myFunction` since you have called `myFunction` directly with `"variable"`. Since `this` is the `window` object, it doesn't have have an attribute called `data-id`, which is why you are getting `undefined`.

To get around this, you can do explicitly set `this` while calling `myFunction` like so:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    myFunction.call(this, 'variable');
});
```

I'm not sure why you want to return the argument you passed in, but you should be able to get it back with the `return` from `myFunction` if you take this approach.

Comment: That makes sense. How would I make this data-id without calling it in the click function?

Comment: This makes sense too - thank you. The reason I am doing it is because I want to call the same function twice and in the function I want to be able to have a variable show as variable++ or variable-- dependent on how it is passed in. Is there a better way to do this? I am a little puzzled.

Comment: Ah, so you want a counter of sorts? I guess that's one way to do it. But it's probably better to maintain a separate variable that is accessible from any function.

Comment: Check out http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gynpo pen more to see a more specific version of what I'm trying to accomplish. It would be ideal for me to have increase and decrease click handlers, and based on which one is clicked all the code runs but changes quantity++ or quantity-- respectively.

Comment: @James You can post that as a separate question. There are multiple ways to do that.

Comment: Separate question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708849/passing-value-into-function-and-variable-scope-in-jquery  - hope I phrased it correctly!

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` only works if you're using it in a function called as part of a jQuery method. If you use it in a "standalone" function like `myFunction`, it'll come back as undefined (because the scope of `myFunction` is `window`, not the jQuery element that called it).

You can create a variable to store the value of `$(this)`, then pass it to `myFunction`:

```
function myFunction(data, target) {
  var a = target.attr('data-id');
  console.log(a);
  return data;
}

$('.btn').click(function(){
  var target = $(this);
  myFunction('variable', target);
});
```

Or, if you don't need to call myFunction from anywhere else, you could skip the middleman and combine them:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
  var a = $(this).attr('data-id');
  alert(a);
});
```

Then you can use $(this) and save space.