# Passing value into function and variable scope in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scope

Link to code example:

http://jsfiddle.net/99Shr/

This code works for a given click handler, and **$(this)** takes on the particular class.

I am attempting to take the code that is inside the click function and put it into it's own function. The reason I want to do this is because I would like to replace quantity-- with quantity++ depending on which click handler is called. The issue I am running into is that the variables when called in the function are undefined since **$(this)** is window.

I am well aware that I may be doing this wrong to achieve what I want and am open to learning a better way to achieve it.

```
function price(change) {
   return change;
}

$('.cart-item-decrease').click(function(){
   price('quantity--');
});
```

or

```
$('.cart-item-increase').click(function(){
   price('quantity++');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can customise the event handler registration so that additional data gets sent to your function:

```
function myClickHandler(e)
{
    // ...
    quantity += e.data.increment;
    // ...
}

$('.cart-item-increase').on('click', null, {
  increment: 1
}, myClickHandler);

$('.cart-item-decrease').on('click', null, {
  increment: -1
}, myClickHandler);
```

Here, the `increment` property gets sent to `myClickHandler` as `e.data.increment`.

Comment: Wow, this is super clever and works just as expected. I didn't think of passing data like that. Checked out the on() documentation on jQuery's website and it makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: @James Yeah, I don't use it often, but in cases like these it comes in quite handy :)

Comment: I noticed an issue with this implementation. Now that it is part of a function, if there are 2 rows of products in the cart, and I click increase on one row, it changes both rows instead of just the one. Any idea?

Comment: @James `this` still references the element that was clicked, so you should only update that one in particular.

Comment: Hmm, it was doing both rows. I will have to look into that. Another question. Say I want to pass in data such as productPrice: price + linePrice.. I am unable to do that. Is there a way to pass that in as a string, but in the function make it into an operation?

Comment: @James If price and linePrice have a common ancestor element, you could use `.closest()` and/or `.siblings()` to find the elements that you need. Hope that helps.

Comment: @James Any more problems with this approach? :)

Comment: It worked – thanks for checking in. I am having some trouble in my code can see that I am repeating code because I am unsure of how to put it in a function and still make it still work. If you have time I could show you where I am stuck.